# ManyToMany on Self Model: How to add new instances to this relation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a `Profile` class, which extends the `User` class, and I would like to allow every `profile` to be able to bookmark other user profiles.

I've set up the following:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
     # some fields e.g. name, email
     bookmarked_profiles = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

Now, I'm a bit confused, for example, how would I 'bookmark' new profiles for a given profile instance?

E.g. something like

```
# add new bookmark for profile instance
p = Profile.objects.get(pk=1)
profiles_to_bookmark = Profile.objects.all()
p.bookmarked_profiles = profiles_to_bookmark
```

I would also like to know the number of bookmarked profiles e.g.

`p.bookmarked_profiles.count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in django docs, there is everything that you need there

```
  for profile in profiles_to_bookmark:
      p.bookmarked_profiles.add(profile) # WIll add New objects

  p.bookmarked_profiles.all() # Will return all objects

  p.bookmarked_profiles.all().count() # Will return count of objects
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding the queryset via `add()` available in [`ManyToMnayField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)

```
p = Profile.objects.get(pk=1)
profiles_to_bookmark = Profile.objects.all()
p.bookmarked_profiles.add(*profiles_to_bookmark) #Note the star *
```

And with `all()` you can set all bookmarked profiles, and `count()` will return the total

```
p.bookmarked_profiles.all()
p.bookmarked_profiles.count()
```